# While passing id from a json to an URL, undefined value is getting passed

Tags: javascript, json

I've a sample JSON as given below:

```
[
    {
        "componentid": 4,
        "displayImageUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/350x200",
        "title": "theme",
        "shortdesc": "to set theme for different applications"
    },
    {
        "componentid": 7,
        "displayImageUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/350x200",
        "title": "preferences",
        "shortdesc": "preferences screen for apps"
    }
]
```

And I prepared a HTML content based on that data. Code is given below:

```
function prepareTopComponentList(data) {

    var preparedHtml = "";

    for (var count = 0; count < data.length; count++) {
        preparedHtml += "<div class=\"col-lg-4\" style=\"margin-top: 20px\">\n" +
            "                <div class=\"card wow fadeIn\" data-wow-delay=\"0.2s\">\n" +
            "                    <img class=\"img-fluid\" src=\"";
        preparedHtml += data[0].displayImageUrl;
        preparedHtml += "\" alt=\"N/A\">\n" +
            "                    <div class=\"card-body\">\n" +
            "                        <h4 class=\"card-title\">";
        preparedHtml += data[0].title;
        preparedHtml += "</h4>\n" +
            "                        <p class=\"card-text\">";
        preparedHtml += data[0].shortdesc;
        preparedHtml += "</p>\n" +
            "                        <a onclick = \"redirect(this, this);\" href='#' class=\"btn btn-info\" id=\"";
        preparedHtml += "component_desc_" + data[count].componentid;

        /*I replaced 0 with count so that we can get proper ids*/
        //console.log(data[0].componentid);

        preparedHtml += "\">Learn more</a>\n" +
            "                    </div>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "                </div>\n" +
            "            </div>";
    }

    $("#div_top_component").append(preparedHtml);

}
```

Now, I'm redirecting to a page based on value of `componentid`. Redirection function code is given below:

```
function redirect(element, data) {  
    // data = prepareTopComponentList(data);
    for (var count = 0; count < data.length; count++) {
        var url = "inside.dell.com";
        var query = data[count].componentid;
        var finalUrl = "inside.dell.com/componentid=" + query;
        console.log(finalUrl);
    }
    window.location = "inside.dell.com/componentid=" + query;
}
```

When I run this code, I get this error:

```
The requested URL /Reusable Components/pages/inside.dell.com/componentid=undefined was not found on this server.
```

That error is fine, I don't have any problem with that. However in redirection URL, component id is `undefined`. How do I make sure that value of component ID gets passed to URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML

```
"<a onclick = \"redirect(" + data[count].componentid + ");\" href='#' class=\"btn btn-info\" id=\"";
```

And then your function

```
function redirect(id) {  
    window.location = "inside.dell.com/componentid=" + id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `query` used for `windows.location` is defined in the `for` loop block and therefore is undefined outside of it.

Answer (score 1):

Declare your `query` variable outside of for loop.

```
function redirect(element, data) {  
// data = prepareTopComponentList(data);
var query;
for (var count = 0; count < data.length; count++) {
    var url = "inside.dell.com";
    query = data[count].componentid;
    var finalUrl = "inside.dell.com/componentid=" + query;
    console.log(finalUrl);
}
window.location = "inside.dell.com/componentid=" + query;
}
```